# std::list и фрагментация памяти

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот якобы поговаривают, что, если постоянно, непрерывно выделять и освобождать небольшие куски памяти ну грубо скажем от 100 байт до 2Кбайт, к примеру std::list`ом к примеру в условном северном приложении - то якобы может случится фрагментация памяти ну или адресного пространства и может получится так, что памяти реально много - условно 1 Гб, а выделит память под объектом размером всего 1Кб уже не удается.

Такое реально возможно в современных ОС ?

Comment: в 32битных может. в 64 - не уверен, но тут может быть другая проблема - менеждер памяти может долго бегать по свои структурам в поисках следующего места для выделения памяти. Плюс, данные теперь могут лежать разбросанными по всей памяти, а это плохо для кеша. И получается просадка на ровном месте.   я когда то экспериментировал с этим на реальном боевом приложеними - у меня был список клиентов, всего то около 1000, но в него часто добавляли-удаляли и бегали по нему. И замена вектора на list дала невероятную просадку.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Фрагментация памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/180995).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Фрагментация памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180995/%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8)